# How can I draw a vertical line on every page of a document?

Tags: backgrounds

I want to draw a vertical line on the left of every odd-numbered page and on the right of every even-numbered page in a document. Is there a preamble to do this?

Comment: maybe http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/ can help

Comment: The `background` package can do this very easily.

Comment: Or you could use any pagestyle modifier (such as `fancyhdr`) and put it e.g. as `tikzpicture` into one head (the sledgehammer-to-crack-a-nut-version).

Comment: There is also the everypage and tikzpagenodes packages.  The everypage hook is executed after the page is complete and before the headers and footers are added.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but unfortunately I do not know enough LaTeX to implement them. Could anyone supply an example, please?

Comment: All the listed packages come with manuals.

Answer (score 1):

This draws a line `0.5\marginparsep` to the left or right of the text area.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\AddEverypageHook{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
  \ifodd\value{page}\draw ($(current page text area.north west)+(-0.5\marginparsep,0pt)$)
    -- ($(current page text area.south west)+(-0.5\marginparsep,0pt)$);
  \else\draw ($(current page text area.north east)+(0.5\marginparsep,0pt)$)
    -- ($(current page text area.south east)+(0.5\marginparsep,0pt)$);
  \fi}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum [1-16]
\end{document}
```