# footer hiding page number

Tags: footer

I am writing a manual for my team at work, and I have some trouble here 
I want a colored line at bottom of each page so I make a definition for the color then use it in the footer it looks nice 
but the problem is it remove the page number !!!

please help me in away to keep both the line and page numbers
thank you in advance

```
\documentclass [14pt]  {extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage {multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%____________________________________________________________
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 
\fancyfoot[C]{\color{cadetblue}\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{30pt}}}  
%____________________________________________________________

\definecolor{cadetblue}{rgb}{0.37, 0.62, 0.63}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

%LOGO
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}    
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2}
\end{minipage}

\begin{center}
\vfill
{\textbf{\myfont TITLE }}}\\  

\vfill
\end{center}

\begin{flushleft}
AAAAAA Co.\\
SSSSSSSSSS Department\\
\vspace{3mm} 
Created by :\\ 
FFFFFFFF\\
\vspace{3mm}  
Reviewed by :\\ 
AAAAAAA \\
\end{flushleft}

{\color{cadetblue}\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{18pt}}}
\end{titlepage}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{\uppercase {Introduction}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please reduce you non-complete example to the minimal version that has this issue and please don't let it die out in the middle of nowhere, i.e. there is no `\end{document}` etc.

Comment: If you want to have the line show up on EVERY page (such as the title page) you can use the everypage package (and tikz).  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353891/how-can-i-draw-a-vertical-line-on-every-page-of-a-document/354058?s=9|0.0459#354058 for example.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to put both the line and the page number in the same footer by overlapping two `\makebox{\textwidth]`s.

I minimized your MWE a bit.  Also, I don't understand why the `\rule` showed up under the baseline, but it does without having to *raise* it.

```
\documentclass [14pt]  {extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}% NWE only

%____________________________________________________________
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 
\fancyfoot[C]{\rlap{\makebox[\textwidth]{\thepage}}%
\makebox[\textwidth]{\color{cadetblue}\rule{\paperwidth}{\dimexpr 0.7in-\footskip}}}
%____________________________________________________________

\definecolor{cadetblue}{rgb}{0.37, 0.62, 0.63}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Further experiments showed that if you `\leavevmode` before the `\rlap` the rule will show up above the baseline.